# Трансформация массива объектов JS

Tags: javascript

Массив объектов вида:

```
const dayTransactions = [
    { currency: 'USD', amount: 60, operation: 'sell' },
    { currency: 'EUR', amount: 160, operation: 'buy' },
    { currency: 'EUR', amount: 90, operation: 'sell' },
];
```

Нужно привести, учитывая 'sell' и 'buy', к виду:

```
[
  {USD: 60},
  {EUR: 70}
]
```

Comment: по каким правилам нужно _учитывать 'sell' и 'buy'_?

Comment: sell ето '-' по деньгам, buy + по деньгам

Comment: тогда почему оба числа положительные в примере?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предположим, что комментаторы выше правы. И вам действительно нужно найти разницу между sell и buy по каждому currency. Тогда предлагаю воспользоваться [.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

```js
const dayTransactions = [
    { currency: 'USD', amount: 60, operation: 'sell' },
    { currency: 'EUR', amount: 160, operation: 'buy' },
    { currency: 'EUR', amount: 90, operation: 'sell' },
];

const con = (obj) => obj.reduce((acc, rec) => {
  return { ...acc, [rec.currency]: (acc[rec.currency] || 0) + (rec.amount * (rec.operation === 'sell' ? 1 : -1)) }
  }, {})

console.log(con(dayTransactions));
```

Answer (score 2):

Логично было бы сделать, если `sell` - то прирост денег. 
Если `buy` то минус денег. 
Соответственно и разница должны быть `sell - buy`, в Вашем варианте -70, а не 70.

```js
    let val = [
    { currency: 'USD', amount: 60, operation: 'sell' },
    { currency: 'EUR', amount: 160, operation: 'buy' },
    { currency: 'EUR', amount: 90, operation: 'sell' },
    ];

    let result = new Object();
    let result1 = [];
    for(let i=0;i<val.length;i++){
        if (typeof result[val[i]['currency']] !== "undefined") {
            if(val[i]['operation'] == 'sell'){
                result[val[i]['currency']] += val[i]['amount'];
            } else if(val[i]['operation'] == 'buy'){
                result[val[i]['currency']] -= val[i]['amount'];
            }
        } else {
            if (val[i]['operation'] == 'sell') {
                result[val[i]['currency']] = val[i]['amount'];
            } else if (val[i]['operation'] == 'buy') {
                result[val[i]['currency']] = -1 * val[i]['amount'];
            }
        }
    }
    result1.push(result);

    console.log(result1);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) метод `reduce()` применяет функцию `reducer` к каждому элементу массива (слева-направо), возвращая одно результирующее значение.

```js
const dayTransactions = [
    { currency: 'USD', amount: 60, operation: 'sell' },
    { currency: 'EUR', amount: 160, operation: 'buy' },
    { currency: 'EUR', amount: 90, operation: 'sell' },
];

const res = dayTransactions.reduce(
    (acc, x) => {
        if (!(x.currency in acc)) {
            acc[x.currency] = 0;
        }
        acc[x.currency] += (x.operation === 'sell' ? -1 : 1) * x.amount;
        return acc;
    },
    {}
);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Осталось только узнать, что имеется в виду под `sell` и `buy` -1 и +1 соответственно или наоборот))